# Bubble-sorting rows of Fortran 2D array

Tags: fortran

I am working on the second part of an assignment which asks me to reorder a matrix such that each row is in monotonically increasing order and so that the first element of each row is monotonically increasing. If two rows have the same initial value, the rows should be ordered by the second element in the row.  If those are both the same, it should be the third element, continuing through the last element.

I have written a bubble sort that works fine for the first part (reordering each row). I have written a bubble sort for the second part (making sure that the first element of each row is monotonically increasing). However, I am running into an infinite loop and I do not understand why.

I do understand that the issue is that my "inorder" variable is not eventually getting set to true (which would end the while loop). However, I do not understand why inorder is not getting set to true. My logic is the following: once the following code has swapped rows to the point that the rows are all in order, we will pass through the while loop one more time (and inorder will get set to true), which will cause the while loop to end. I am stumped as to why this isn't happening.

```
inorder = .false.
loopA: do while ( .not. inorder ) !While the rows are not ordered
    inorder = .true.
        loopB: do i = 1, rows-1 !Iterate through the first column of the array
            if (arr(i,1)>arr(i+1,1)) then !If we find a row that is out of order
                inorder = .false.
                tempArr = arr(i+1,:) !Swap the corresponding rows
                arr(i+1,:) = arr(i,:)
                arr(i,:) = tempArr
            end if

            if (arr(i,1)==arr(i+1,1)) then !The first elements of the rows are the same
                loopC: do j=2, cols !Iterate through the rest of the row to find the first element that is not the same
                    if (arr(i,j)>arr(i+1,j)) then !Found elements that are not the same and that are out of order
                        inorder = .false.
                        tempArr = arr(i+1,:) !Swap the corresponding rows
                        arr(i+1,:) = arr(i,:)
                        arr(i,:) = tempArr
                    end if
                end do loopC
           end if
        end do loopB
end do loopA
```

Example input:

```
  6    3    9   23   80
  7   54   78   87   87
 83    5   67    8   23
102    1   67   54   34
 78    3   45   67   28
 14   33   24   34    9
```

Example (correct) output (that my code is not generating):

```
  1   34   54   67  102
  3    6    9   23   80
  3   28   45   67   78
  5    8   23   67   83
  7   54   78   87   87
  9   14   24   33   34
```

It is also possible that staring at this for hours has made me miss something stupid, so I appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you get to compare rows where the first element is identical, you then go through the whole array and compare every single item.

So if you have two arrays like this:

```
1 5 3
1 2 4
```

Then the first element is the same, it enters the second part of your code.

In second place, 5>2, so it swaps it:

```
1 2 4
1 5 3
```

But then it doesn't stop. In third place, 4>3, so it swaps it back

```
1 5 3
1 2 4
```

And now you're back to where you were.

Cheers